# BGFX and double buffering

Tags: gpu, framebuffer, bgfx

Does [BGFX](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx) internally double buffer everything? Or is this the application programmer's responsibility?

All the BGFX [examples](https://bkaradzic.github.io/bgfx/examples.html) that render-off screen don't seem create double the buffers.

Would I need to call [createFrameBuffer()](https://bkaradzic.github.io/bgfx/bgfx.html#frame-buffers) twice, once for front and once for back, and render them alternately?

I want to avoid unnecessary stalls of the GPU. In OpenGL I would have done this via [buffer orphaning](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming). But I have a suspicion that in BGFX I may have to do this more explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transient buffers in bgfx do use orphaning. See [code here](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx/blob/276598ad50d33f1d1a56311520b17390a6bed635/src/renderer_gl.h#L1290), which is called [here](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx/blob/276598ad50d33f1d1a56311520b17390a6bed635/src/renderer_gl.cpp#L7042).

If you're not using transient data, then yes I think you have to do it more explicitly.

For instance, the "27-terrain" example does dynamic streaming of vertex data, and allows you to switch among several modes at runtime. You can see the logic [here](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx/blob/276598ad50d33f1d1a56311520b17390a6bed635/examples/27-terrain/terrain.cpp#L233). The default case just destroys/recreates the buffer every time. Note the different calls in the different cases: `createVertexBuffer` vs `createDynamicVertexBuffer`.